# Parse List<String> as JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I'm following the book Real-World Software Development and the current chapter was about writing a `BankStatementCSVParser` which reads a file like this:

```
30-01-2017,-100, Deliveroo
30-01-2017,-50, Tesco
01-02-2017,6000, Salary
02-02-2017,2000, Royalties
02-02-2017,-4000, Rent
03-02-2017,3000, Tesco
05-02-2017,-30, Cinema
```

and parses each line and outputs an object of this class:

```
public class BankTransaction {
    private final LocalDate date;
    private final double amount;
    private final String description;

    public BankTransaction(final LocalDate date, final double amount, 
           final String description) {
        this.date = date;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

This works fine and CSV was easy (especially since I was copying the book...), the problem came at the end of the chapter when I was asked to implement `BankStatementJSONParser` on my own if I could.

I've tried woth GSON and Jackson and I can't really get any example to work since my `BankTransaction` class is immutable and doesn't allow setters.

I managed to get one solution working but it's horrible to look at:

```
public List<BankTransaction> parseLinesFrom(List<String> lines) {
    Map<String, ?> map = new Gson().fromJson(String.join(" ", lines), Map.class);
    List<?> listOfTransactions = (List<?>) map.get("transactions");

    List<BankTransaction> bankTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfTransactions.forEach(rawJson -> {
        LinkedTreeMap<String, ?> javaJson = (LinkedTreeMap<String, ?>) rawJson;

        final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(javaJson.get("date").toString(), DATE_PATTERN);
        final double amount = Double.parseDouble(javaJson.get("amount").toString());
        final String description = javaJson.get("description").toString();
        BankTransaction newTransaction = new BankTransaction(localDate, amount, description);
        bankTransactions.add(newTransaction);
    });
    return bankTransactions;
}
```

Thankful for any insights how I can make this less ugly, maybe the problem is with my self-written .json file:

```
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "date": "30-01-2017",
      "amount": -100,
      "description": "Deliveroo"
    },
    {
      "date": "01-02-2017",
      "amount": 6000,
      "description": "Salary"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does annotating the constructor with `@JsonCreator` and its paramaters with `@JsonProperty` solve your problem? Than you could deserialize with jackson directly: `objectMapper.readValue(input, List.class)`

Comment: This may be the solution to your problem: [How to de/serialize an immutable object without default constructor using ObjectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568353/how-to-de-serialize-an-immutable-object-without-default-constructor-using-object)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, It almost worked but it didn't like the date field it seems, tried adding some @JsonFormat but it kept complaining about illegal reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different solutions to your problem:

1. You could create your own [TypeAdapter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) to parse the List
2. You could use [TypeToken](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)s to tell Gson at runtime what you will load (this will most certainly break the field `date` though)
3. You could create your own [JsonDeserializer](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)

I personally would do the second one and create a custom [TypeAdapter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) just for the LocalDate, which gets automatically applied by Gson after registering it.

Comment: Thank you, I did as you said but using Jackson. It was rather complicated for me but now I feel it's less magic going on :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the method described by the accepted answer but in Jackson instead of GSON by overriding the Jackson ObjectMapper and accepting a DateTimeFormatter in the constructor:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
public CustomObjectMapper(DateTimeFormatter pattern){
    SimpleModule customModule = new SimpleModule("LocalDateMapper");
    customModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new JsonSerializer<LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            ToStringSerializer.instance.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
        }
    });
    customModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            return LocalDate.parse(p.getText(), pattern);
        }
    });

    registerModule(customModule);

}
```

}